# Can I fix tabs on top of a viewpager?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have implemented a TitlePageIndicator that can swipe between fragments, but I would like to have fixed tabs at the bottom of the screen that do not move when the user is swiping through the fragments.

I started implementing this feature in the standard way but realized my host activity cannot extend both TabActivity AND FragmentActivity.  What would be the correct way to do something like this?  My thoughts were that I would have to implement my own tabs instead of using TabHost and TabWidget.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FragmentTabsPager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html) (TabsAdapter that extends FragmentPagerAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabLayout as following

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_dialog">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/gray2"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/gray2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```